# Corda Accounts:Issue with SyncKeyMappingFlow to Synchronize publicKeys

Tags: blockchain, corda

In our Corda Project we are having two nodes, Node-A and Node-B. An account is created on Node-A and shared with Node-B. From Node-A We have requested a publickey using  `new RequestKeyForAccount(accountInfo)`. Node-B is not aware of this public key. So to synchronize the public keys We have invoked `new SyncKeyMappingFlow(flowSession, Collections.singletonList(anonymousParty))` from Node-A. We have also implemented a responder flow on Node-B which invokes the `new SyncKeyMappingFlowHandler(flowSession))` subflow. Both the initiator and responder flow are working fine. When tried to look up the List of publickeys belonging to the account on the Node-B using `accountService.accountKeys(accountInfo.getState().getData().getLinearId().getId()).toString())` we are getting an Empty list. Ideally we should be getting the public key that we requested on the Node-A. Is this this the appropriate approach to synchronize the public keys? Suggest an alternative approach if this is a flawed approach.

Comment: Before syncing the key mapping; can you confirm that Node-B actually received the account that was created on Node-A? Can you query it on Node-B? Also check the logs of your nodes and see if there any useful messages there.

Comment: The Account is shared with Node-B right after the creation of the account. But as mentioned in the bellow answer I am getting only the accounts created on the Node-B( account shared by Node-A is not returned as part of ```accountservice.ouraccounts())```.I have checked the Node-B and Node-A logs and found no errors.

Comment: `ourAccounts()` only returns the accounts where the current node is the `host`; Node-B is not the host.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, the `accountKey` will only return the keys which have been generated on the calling node.

Here is the reference:
https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/services/AccountService.kt#L66